# How can I get a rid of the little black box before the video plays with the Outstream renderer from Xandr?

Tags: android-videoview, prebid.js, video-ads

I'm using the renderer from Xandr to play Video ads, and I'm having a little black box before the video appears on the page. Would anyone know why is this happening?

Xandr's Outstream Player options here: https://docs.xandr.com/bundle/monetize_monetize-standard/page/topics/outstream-video-player-options.html

[image]

This seems to be an issue with the library provided by Xandr, and it can't be changed. Maybe some parameters can get rid of it. It's happening on Mobile on Android not on desktop.

Comment: could you share a test page ?

Comment: Thanks here is a test page: https://adserver.online/test/test_black.html. To replicate go on Mobile/Android. Maybe something to do with the browser, like a placeholder while the video loads.